# Apollo GraphQL failing connection

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

My root component is already wrapped with an ApolloProvider tag, but the error message tells me it is not.

**Error Message**

```
Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option. Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>, or pass an ApolloClient instance in via options.

This error is located at:
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
```

Problem is my root component is already wrapped with an ApolloProvider tag

## React Native Code

**IMPORT statements**

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  useQuery,
  ApolloProvider,
  gql,
} from "@apollo/client";
```

**CONNECTION WITH GraphQL**

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://www.outvite.me/gql/gql",
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  defaultOptions: { watchQuery: { fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network' } },
})
```

**TEST QUERY**

```
const USER_QUERY = gql`
  query USER {
    users {
      nodes {
        edge {
          username
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

**DEFAULT APP**

THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS BEING THROWN

const { data, loading } = useQuery(USER_QUERY) is the line that traceback shows

```
export default function App() {
    const { data, loading } = useQuery(USER_QUERY)
    return (
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
           <View>
             <Text style={styles.text}>Open</Text>
             <Text style={styles.text}>Another text</Text>
           </View>
           <Button title="Toggle Sidebar" onPress={() => toggleSidebarView()} />
           <Button title="Change theme" onPress={() => toggleColorTheme()} />
        </ApolloProvider>
    );
}
```

Comment: follow docs/tuts more strictly - you're trying to use hook and later render required by hook provider - don't you see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the `useQuery` hook only works if you're in a component that is already wrapped in the `ApolloProvider` so you probably want to do something like this

```
export default function MainApp() {
    const { data, loading } = useQuery(USER_QUERY)
    return (
      <View>
        ... use 'data' in here somewhere...
      </View>
    );
}
```

and then the top-level `App` component would look like

```
export default function App() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <MainApp />
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
}
```